# Git hook to update superproject on submodule change?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-submodules, azure-pipelines, githooks

I have three git repositories: `A`, `B`, and `C`. `C` is a superproject including submodules `A` and `B`, tracking each submodule's respective master branch.

When the master branch of `A` or `B` is changed, I must do the following in `C`:

```
git submodule update --remote
git add A
git add B
git commit -m "Update submodule A or B"
git push
```

At this point an automated build and deploy from C is executed.

I'm looking for ways to streamline this process. Ideally, any commit to the master branch of `A` or `B` would trigger a hook to update, commit, and push to `C`. Any ideas how to achieve this?

Edit: In case there's a vendor-specific feature I should be aware of, I'm using Azure DevOps for the git hosting and Azure Pipelines for the build and deploy process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a git post-commit [hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), when you do a commit in the submodules the hook will be executed and will do the commands.

1. Go to each sub module repo.
2. Create file *.git/hooks/post-commit* with following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

   if [ "$branch" = "master" ]; then
     cd {super repo location}
     git submodule update --remote
     git add A
     git add B
     git commit -m "Update submodule A or B"
     git push
   fi
   ```
3. Make it executable (not required on *Windows*):

   ```
   $ chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit
   ```