# Is there any way to automatically update git submodule in remote (bitbucket)?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, bitbucket, git-submodules, bitbucket-pipelines

I have CI/CD pipeline in my parent git repository. But whenever I commit new changes in submodule, I have to update the parent repository again. This is quite painful now.
Is there any way to automatically update the submodule.
I am using Bitbucket.

I found [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/How-to-make-the-parent-git-folder-always-point-to-latest-commit/qaq-p/1783602) but solution seems vague to me.

Comment: Create a job on the parent repo to update the submodule, add a ci action to call this job on your submodule cicd

Comment: [`post-commit` hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54901456/7976758). It runs locally, after a commit in the submodule.